# Guru of the Week #2 no match for the operator==

Tags: c++

From [Guru of the Week #2](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/002.htm). We have the original function:

```
string FindAddr( list<Employee> l, string name )
{
    for( list<Employee>::iterator i = l.begin(); // (1)
         i != l.end(); 
         i++ ) 
    {
        if( *i == name ) // (2)
        {
            return (*i).addr;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I added dummy Employee class to that:

```
class Employee
{
    string n;
public:
    string addr;

    Employee(string name) : n(name) {}
    Employee() {}

    string name() const
    {
        return n;
    }

    operator string()
    {
        return n;
    }
};
```

And got compilation error:

In place (1):

```
conversion from ‘std::_List_const_iterator<Employee>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::_List_iterator<Employee>’ requested
```

In place (2):

```
no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘i.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = Employee]() == name’
```

To eliminate first one, we change `iterator` to `const_iterator`. And the only way to eliminate second error, is to write own operator==. **However, Herb Sutter wrote that:**

> The Employee class isn't shown, **but for this to work it must either have a conversion to string or a conversion ctor taking a string**.

But Employee has a conversion function and conversion constructor. GCC version 4.4.3. Compiled normally, `g++ file.cpp` without any flags.

There should be implicit conversion and it should work, why it doesn't? I don't want operator==, I just want it work like Sutter said, with *a conversion to string or a conversion ctor taking a string*.

Comment: Can you reverse the comparison operands and try? Like this - `if( name == *i )`.

Comment: @vvnraman error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘name == i.std::_List_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = Employee]()’

Comment: If you want to eliminate the first error by replacing `iterator` with `const_iterator`, then you also have to declare your conversion operator as `operator string() const` (note the `const` at the end). If you don't, it will become non-callable, since `*i` will become constant. Better simply remove `const` from declaration of `l` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Herb Sutter is wrong in this case (I don't have a copy of "Exceptional C++", but I'd expect this GotW entry to be cleaned up for the book.)

But first, in order to get to the error in question, you have to remove the `const` from the `l` parameter declaration. (Note, that replacing `iterator` with `const_iterator` will only obfuscate the problem: your `operator string()` is not `const`, meaning that it is not callable for constant object `*i`).

Once you fix the first problem, your code will indeed fail to compile at

```
if( *i == name )
```

line. This happens because function `std::operator ==` that compares `std::string` objects is actually defined by the Standard Library as a *template* function

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
bool operator==(
  const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
  const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs);
```

In order for this function to participate in overload resolution, its template arguments have to be successfully deduced. This is impossible in your context, since in `*i == name` one argument is `std::string` and another is `Employee`. Template argument deduction fails and, for this reason, this template function is not considered for overload resolution. Having no other candidates, the compiler reports an error.

For this reason Herb Sutter's claim that the code should be compilable in presence of `operator string()` conversion function in `Employee` class is incorrect. The code might compile with some specific implementation of Standard Library that declares a dedicated non-template comparison operator for `std::string`, but normally Standard Library implementations don't do it that way.

He also makes another unfounded claim, insisting that the result of that conversion must be a temporary. In reality `Employee` class can have `operator const string &() const` conversion function, which would create no temporaries (return a reference to a data member instead, as it could be done in your example).

Finally, his claim that conversion constructor will make this code work is only true if the program declares a dedicated `operator ==` for `Employee vs. Employee` comparisons. Without introducing such dedicated operator, the conversion constructor will have no effect on the validity of this code. I.e. in your example there was no point in declaring `Employee(string name)` constructor - it does not achieve anything.

Comment: @Adam: but it's very related to the real problem, which is that a `const Employee` is not convertable to a string.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the code is allowed to compile, but not required to. Remember that `string` is a typedef for `basic_string<char>`, it is not a class by itself. Minimal example:

```
template <typename T>
struct basic_string
{
};

typedef basic_string<char> string;

struct Employee
{
    operator string() const;
};

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const basic_string<T>& a, const basic_string<T>& b);

// Compilation succeeds when this is uncommented
// bool operator==(const basic_string<char>& a, const basic_string<char>& b);

bool f(const Employee& e, const string& s)
{
    return e == s; // error
}
```

Yes, `Employee` is convertible to `string`, but it isn't *really* a `string`, so that is not good enough to determine which template argument to use for `operator==`.

If an extra overload specifically for `operator==(const string&, const string&)` is added, it works, and another standard library implementation might provide just that overload. If it is provided, the code will compile, but it's an extension not required by standard C++.

**Edit**: actually, as others have mentioned, that isn't quite enough (`const` issues), but even if fixing the other issues, this remains, and I believe this is the answer to your core question.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: the code of the question had already changed by the time I had written up and posted this. The code is no longer a quote of the GOTW code. It's different code, and the alleged compilation error is apparently not correct either, but I let this answer (to the original posting) stand since it mostly concerns other issues (I am not going to chase a series of edits to the question by correspondingly editing and reworking this answer).

@Vaibhav has [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279585/464581) the core question, namely that the conversion needs to be explicitly expresssed.

But since the cited GOTW (Guru Of The Week) concerns needless temporaries, your class `Employee` code,

```
class Employee
{
    string n;
public:
    string addr;

    Employee(string name) : n(name) {}
    Employee() {}

    string name() const
    {
        return n;
    }

    operator string()
    {
        return n;
    }

};
```

repeat some of the pitfalls discussed in that GOTW.

In

```
Employee(string name) : n(name) {}
```

taking the string argument by values is fine for C++11, because a copy will be created anyway. But then you should **`move`** this value into the member,

```
Employee(string name) : n(move(name)) {}
```

Then, your

```
operator string()
{
    return n;
}
```

suffers from not being `const`, so that it can't be called on a `const` object, so that that object would needlessly have to be copied in order to call this operator.

So, technically, do

```
operator string() const
{
    return n;
}
```

But at the design level even this is *wrong*. An employee isn't a string. For which string would one expect an employee to convert to? His or her name? An employee code? Social security number?

Implicit conversions are generally troublesome, and this is an example of that. It doesn't help to make it `explicit`. Since the relevant string is already available via a named operation (which is the good thing to do), it would improve the class much simply to *remove* this conversion operator.

Comment: @MooingDuck: the general answer to make it compile is, as I wrote, "@Vaibhav has already answered", namely make that comparision explicit. For the details of why something doesn't compile, you need to provide an *unchanging, complete example*. Then those details might be discussed.

Answer (score 0):

You receive an Employee object from the iterator, so *i is pointing to an Employee object. You then need to point to that employee's name.

Try this:

```
if( (*i).name == name )
```

Comment: You're missing the point of the question, I think. The question isn't how to make it work, but why it doesn't work as is (since `Employee` can be converted implicitly to `string` to get a `(string) == (string)` comparison)

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you reverse the operands of the comparison operators? The compiler complains that there is no `operator ==` for `List<>`, but its defined for `string`.

Changing `if( *i == name )` to `if( name == *i )` should work.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘name == i.std::_List_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = Employee]()’

Comment: Yeah. Looked that way after some time. I should have tried it out first.